# Нужна ли запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятую после слова "эксперта": "В соответствии с ходатайством эксперта из ИФНС и ОАО затребованы документы"? При этом смысл предложения что документы затребованы из указанных организаций, а не эксперт из этих организаций.

Answer (score 1):

В связи с ходатайством (или по ходатайству)эксперта затребованы документы из ИФНС и ОАО.